# Which usage is right - "The file is in the X Drive" or "The file is in X Drive"?

Tags: meaning

When you refer to a file in a certain drive in a computer do you say "The file is in the X Drive" or "The file is in X Drive"? I am told that the 2nd option is the one that is correct.

Comment: This may be me showing my age, but a file lives *on* a drive (but *in* a folder/directory); only a disc can be *in* a drive.

Comment: I usually say the file is ***on drive X***. But I think anyone who wants to defend any particular form as "correct" (and by implication, label the alternatives as "incorrect") is just being pedantic.

Comment: @ChrisH- Well said!

Comment: The file is on the B drive.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - pedantic is the word. But you can't say much if the person being pedantic is your language trainer.

Comment: Google Books, [file is on c drive](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22file+is+on+c+drive%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 1 result, [file is on the c drive](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22file+is+on+the+c+drive%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 5 results, [file is on drive c](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22file+is+on+drive+c%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 178 results. And the single result for [file is **in** drive c](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22file+is+in+drive+c%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is syntactically different. Draw your own conclusions.

Answer (score -1):

The first phrasing is clearer, although the second one is no more incorrect.  A windows-style computer can only have a single directory point mounted at each drive letter, although the drive letters can be re-mapped or point to different UNC paths for different people.

You'd probably be most clear if you were to use the second-person here.

> The file is in *your computer's* X drive.